# Trouble understanding the mechanics+benefits of async in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

On reading [this article](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) it gives the impression that using async can mean that a webserver can concurrently serve more requests than it has threads.

I don't understand how this works though. I do understand (at least I think I understand) that using async one can spin off multiple IO requests without blocking inside a request and without starting a new threads. I believe there's some magic going on but deep within the covers there's probably a call to [`select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net).

However, even then, I still think you need one thread per request. The thread presumably has the current stack, and other information about where execution in that thread is up to (like an instruction pointer). I can't see how one can just trash that information whilst you're waiting for a file descriptor in a `select()` call, lest you forget where you're at and also risk all your active data being garbage collected. But the article first referenced suggested this somehow happens, and I quote:

> Asynchronous requests allow a smaller number of threads to handle a larger number of requests.

I don't really understand the mechanics of how this happens, and to me it seems impossible. Sure, async will reduce the number of *additional* threads to deal with IO requests, but I still can't see how you can avoid at least one thread per request. Unless you do something weird like trashing the thread but saving it's state to the heap and then restoring it later, but I don't really see how that achieves much (you could just apply the thread pool to "running threads" and achieve basically the same thing).

Comment: _[There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)_

Comment: You do use a thread per request. However, if my response is just returning `Hello World` and it takes 1ms to do so, that 1 thread can serve 1000 requests a second. Most web requests don't do the actual processing, it offloads it to a DB or another service. While the DB is fetching your data, that 1 thread that was serving the request, can now go back into the threadpool to serve other requests.

Comment: @JohanP how does it "go back to the threadpool". Like I said in the question, that thread object presumably has important information. If you just get rid of it, how do you return to the request after? You've lost the information of where you're up to and the active variables on the stack.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov a linky boi would be much appreciated if you have one (I could search but I'd appreciate some help pointing out an article that's actually correct because I don't know what is).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov alternatively is there another place I should ask this? StackExchange Software Engineering? I read both of the metas and it seemed like StackOverflow was the more appropriate place because the question is about coding, not the software development process, but I may be wrong.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/